# 16.04 LTS Auto/Manual Ethernet Configuration

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, lan

I've Fiber Internet at home.

As usual, ISP has provided a Modem and a Wireless-Router (DIR-615).

**What Works?**

On **Windows** machine I can connect to Internet in different ways:

1. Directly to Modem (manual session authentication)
2. Through Router (automatic-authentication)

Through Router I can use Wireless or Wired. i.e Using WiFi or Local-Network(RJ45 loop). DHCP has no issues here.

On **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** I can connect to Internet via Router-WiFi only.

**What doesn't Work?**

On **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** I've trouble making it work

1. Directly(Wired) with Modem
2. Through Router Wired, i.e. LAN local loop.

For some reason, Auto-Ethernet worked first time I connected Ubuntu machine to Modem. Later after a session breakup/reboot I can only access Internet via Router-WiFi.

**What I Want/Like**

1. At home I'm on Ubuntu 99% of time & use 99% Internet among family.
2. I prefer Wired-LAN to Modem/Router when I'm active.
3. Let family members access WiFi Access-Point.

---

Hoping I've not messed my configuration up.

Please ask for any information needed to help.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found after looking up on Internet:

**Prelude**

1. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS up-to-date with patches
2. 10 Mbps Duplex Fiber Internet
3. D-Link DIR-615 Router

**Goal**

Automatic Ethernet Configuration for Internet access.

---

Steps that worked for me:

1. Bypass Ethernet from Network Manager
2. Define LAN DHCP on Router
3. Soft Reboot

**Step 1** : You need root access (`sudo` edit)

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
```

`enp1s0` is my Ethernet Card ID, in most cases it's `eth0`.

Now, Network-Manager says `device not managed` for Ethernet.

**Step 2** :

[Router LAN Config](http://192.168.0.1/lan.htm)

My Router LAN page looks like :

On top of it, I threw a static IP for my Ubuntu machine. I think you can skip this.

[image: Router LAN DHCP Configuration]

**Step 3**

Connect RJ45 cable from Router LAN ports with active Internet-session to your machine and then boot it.

**PS :**

I've disabled Wireless (WiFi). It'll will be enabled on Router on demand by family members. Also, I've disabled SSID-Broadcast ;-)

Let me know if there was an easier way to go about it.